# Is there a way to prevent desktop icons from being deleted?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Running Windows 7 Ultimate. I have looked and don't find a group policy setting to prevent a standard user from deleting and/or changing desktop shortcuts...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the user to be able to delete or modify icons you can put them on the public desktop,

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

then ensure your users can only read / traverse / execute but not modify, delete or create to that directory.

```
%userprofile%\Desktop
```

That is the users desktop, and they can always (and **should** always be able to modify most things there.